# error installing mod_wsgi on SUSE 11 server

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

apache version :2.2.6

python versoin :2.6

result of `./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-python=/usr/bin/python` is ok but just got some errors as follows when `make`:

```
....
mod_wsgi.c:14430: error: expected expression before âmoduleâ
mod_wsgi.c:14431: error: expected identifier or â(â before â=â token
mod_wsgi.c:14446: error: expected expression before âmoduleâ
mod_wsgi.c:14447: error: âmodule_dictâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14448: error: âobjectâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14450: error: expected expression before âmoduleâ
mod_wsgi.c:14454: error: âvarsâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14455: error: âargsâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14456: error: âresultâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14457: error: âmethodâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14474: error: âPy_Noneâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14488: error: âPy_Trueâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14491: error: âPy_Falseâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14503: error: âPyExc_TypeErrorâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14519: error: âAuthObjectâ has no member named ârâ
mod_wsgi.c:14523: error: âAuthObjectâ has no member named âlogâ
mod_wsgi.c:14526: error: âPyExc_AttributeErrorâ undeclared (first use in this function)
mod_wsgi.c:14528: error: âAuthObjectâ has no member named âlogâ
mod_wsgi.c:14541: error: expected expression before â)â token
mod_wsgi.c:14548: error: expected â;â before âap_log_rerrorâ
mod_wsgi.c:14553: error: expected â;â before â}â token
mod_wsgi.c:14558: error: too many arguments to function âwsgi_log_python_errorâ
mod_wsgi.c:14563: error: expected expression before âmoduleâ
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

Please advise me

Comment: Not familiar with SUSE, but I believe you need the python development package. Quick google search gives me this: http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse/python-devel.html

Answer (score 1):

i had the same error; i solved it by compileing python 2.7.2 from scratch; if you look around different forums you will see that some libraries of python where compiled on a 32 bit system and you problably are using a 64 bit  system.

go for 2.7 or above 2.6 is a pain to compile due to all the missing dependencies that you have to get. you will end with something like this

Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
bsddb185           dl                 imageop
sunaudiodev
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

Failed to build these modules:
_curses_panel

running build_scripts

this libraries have all been depreciated so it is safe to do a make install as is